# Flutter Save APK file in assets folder to download

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-web

I made an flutter web app which lets the user to download an apk when a button is pressed.Is there's a way to save apk to assets folder and download it when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

There no such thing as asset folder in built application. You should download to shared storage instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Is there a way to preload an apk file with the app and save it to the user's device when they need it.

Comment: What "preload" means for you?

Comment: I have developed an website using flutter for Web now I want to provide user an download button on clicking it starts to download an apk file. I don't want to save the file in firebase or any other online storage. Is there a way to bundle an apk file with the website.

Comment: Sure. Like any other file

Comment: I'm new to flutter, If you don't mind can you provide me an example please.